# Check Homebrew install in order to install Python

Tags: python, macos, installation, homebrew, polymer

I installed Homebrew with help from [this site](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/homebrew-demystified-os-xs-ultimate-package-manager--mac-44884).

Then I was about to install Homebrew's version of Python (since is better than the preinstalled OSX version) [but came across this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/):

> Once you’ve installed Homebrew, insert the Homebrew directory at the
>   top of your PATH environment variable. You can do this by adding the
>   following line at the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

I have no idea what the above reference means.

How do I find out where Homebrew was installed and does the above reference have anything to do with it?

The reason I want to install Python is to simply use its server feature so I can work on a Polymer tutorial.

Comment: hi! have you tinkered around with your .bashrc file? it's a neat little (hidden, thus the `.` prefix) script in your home directory (the command `cd ~` gets you to your home directory) that gets executed when you start your terminal. the tutorial asks you to add the line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` at the end of that script, so that it gets executed every time you're in the terminal. executing that line means ensuring that `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH, which is where the terminal looks for binaries. this, in turn, ensures you can use Homebrew!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew's "install" directory is here: `/usr/local/Cellar/`. The binaries which show up in your shell are here: `/usr/local/bin/`. Adding `/usr/local/bin` to your path means that any binary within that folder can be accessed with just it's name: `foo` instead of having to provide the full path: `/usr/local/bin/foo` each time you want to use it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal run this:

```
printf '\n\nexport PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH\n\n' >> ~/.bashrc
```

That will append the appropriate bit to your PATH env var. Then you can restart your terminal, or run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload your bashrc.

You can tell that it was successful by running `which python`. The system default Python is `/usr/bin/python`, but homebrew's python should be `/usr/local/bin/python` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can edit your `PATH` in Terminal with

```
    sudo nano /etc/paths
```

You will get asked to type your password and this will open the file `/etc/paths` in edit mode in Terminal. You can obviously replace `nano` by any other text editor such as `vi` or `emacs`.

Once the file is open, move the lines `/usr/local/bin`and `/usr/local/sbin` on top so you get to see

```
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/sbin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
```

Save and exit the file, restart Terminal.

You can now run `which python`and check that you get `/usr/local/bin/python`. If not, there is a problem.

**Explanation**: As a result, whenever you open the Terminal and run a command (i.e. a program) such as `python`, your shell will first check if this program is in your local path `/usr/local/bin` (then `/usr/local/sbin`). If it finds it, it will run it. If not, then it will look for it in `/usr/bin`, then in `/bin`, and so on. In other words, the shell proceeds to look for programs in folders according to the order in which their paths appear in `/etc/paths`. Since Homebrew-installed programs (actually symlinks) are in your local path, Homebrew's python (`/usr/local/bin/python`) is now your default python program in Terminal. It will be run instead of the OS X-provided `/usr/bin/python`.